# JavaScript dynamic nav function now working

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I am following the documentation of W3Schools on how to make a dynamic nav element that when the user scrolls down, hide the nav. When the user scrolls up, show the nav. But for some reason unbeknownst to me it is not working. Am i making some novel small mistake or something? im new to web development. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DanielTSutton</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">DANIEL SUTTON_</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about" class="menu-item">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills"class="menu-item">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects"class="menu-item">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"class="menu-item">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="about">
            <span class="about-bg"></span>
        </div> 
        <div id="skills">

        </div>
        <div id="projects">

        </div>
        <div id="contact">

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("nav").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("nav").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```
nav {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFCF2;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to build a dynamic navigation bar and im following the documentation on W3Schools

Comment: what is your folder structure? Also it look like you may be missing some css..

Answer (score 0):

`First` of all, when you use `getElementsByTagName()` you should be careful. Notice how `elements` is plural in the function name. So you should always carefully read the function name. When it is plural, it means you will get an array and in fact if you hover over the function in `vscode` you should see what the return type is.

[image]

In this case it says `HTMLCollection` which is like a fancy array. This means when you look for `nav`, although there is only one element with that tag, it gets returned in an array. So you have something like this: `[theNavElementYouWant]`.

To retrieve that element you should index the array to get the first entry, which is at index zero, like so:

`var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]`

`Secondly`, your navbar's height is set to `100px` by your css code. So if you want to fully hide it, you should set its top position to `-100px` instead of `-50px`.

And `third`, since your navbar's position is `fixed`, then the container below it (div element with `class="container"`) should have `position: absolute;` and `top: 100px;` such that it displays fully under the navbar. In order to see any behaviour at all though, the container's height should be bigger than the visible area on the screen, hence for testing purposes you can add `height: 2000px;` as well. Since you want your navbar to show as soon as you scroll up, then you might want to set the `z-index` of the navbar to be higher than the z-index of the container.

In that case you might want to change the container's position as well through your javascript.

js:

/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var navigation = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0]

    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        navigation.style.top = "0px";
        container.style.top = "100px"
    } else {
        navigation.style.top = "-100px";
        container.style.top = "0px"
    }
    
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

css:

```
nav {
    background-color: violet;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFCF2;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;

    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 0;

    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In many cases of beginners mistakes can happen in the `folder structure` as well. So make sure that you have the folder structure that matches your html imports. By that I mean the paths you use to link the corresponding css and javascript to your webpage. Since you have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">

<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The folder structure should be:

```
project/
...css/
......styles.css
...src/
......index.html
......js/
.........main.js
```

For a working example, checkout this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/z8f4xevk/6/